# scrlayer-notecolumn and listings

Tags: listings, koma-script, minted, scrlayer-notecolumn

Working with a `scrlayer-notecolumn` based margin-note solution I encountered a strange problem: Those notes cannot handle listing content if those inline listings contain a backslash. But they are able to typeset it, if there are no backslashes. This problem is not only specific to `listings` but to `minted` as well.

If you uncomment the lines in the MWE you can reproduce the error. The `minted` command compiles but with the following result:

[image: result]

The `listings` version does not even compile.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,scrlayer-notecolumn,lmodern,listings,minted}    

\begin{document}
Testtext
\makenote{\lstinline{tiny}}
%\makenote{\lstinline{\tiny}}
\makenote{\mintinline{tex}{tiny}}
%\makenote{\mintinline{tex}{\tiny}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sveinung Okay, but then there's another error, I'll edit the post.

Comment: You should not use verbatim commands like `\lstinline` or
`\verb` or verbatim environments like `verbatim` or `lstlisting` in the argument of another command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any kind of *verbatim like* command inside the argument of another command is always problematic. You always need workarounds for it. Already a simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\verb|%$|}
\end{document}
```

cannot work. Using such commands inside the argument of a command like `\section`, that writes to an auxiliary file, is even more problematic.

Using `\lstinline` or `\mintinline` is not less but even more problematic. So at least it should be expected that putting them into the *note* argument of `\makenote` or `\makenote*` does not work. There may be unsufficient workarounds like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,scrlayer-notecolumn,lmodern,listings,minted}    
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-test.tex}
\tiny
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
Testtext
\makenote*{\lstinline{tiny}}% Does work, because "tiny" is unproblematic
\makenote*{\expandafter\lstinline\expandafter|\detokenize{\tiny}|}% Does work
                                % but adds a space after \tiny
\makenote*{\mintinline{tex}{tiny}}% Does work, because "tiny" is unproblematic
\makenote*{\lstinputlisting{\jobname-test.tex}}% Does work.
\end{document}
```

seem to work. But it does only in some cases.

AFAIK, `scrlayer-notecolumn` currently does not support color switching inside the note column, because currently there is no separate color stack for the note columns. So the sense of `minted` in the note column is limited.

Please remember: `scrlayer-notecolumn` is only an experiment, a kind of proof of concept for `scrlayer`. It would need a lot of additional man power to provide things like color stack, floats inside the note columns, footnote inside the note columns etc. I don't think, that the author is willing to provide these things.

Answer (score 1):

You'd like to print code listings into the margin. So your more or less minimal example has to define the note column, like here:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage, scrlayer-notecolumn, lmodern, blindtext,
ragged2e, listings}


\newlength{\paragraphscolwidth}
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
\setlength{\paragraphscolwidth}{.4\textwidth}%
\addtolength{\paragraphscolwidth}{-\marginparsep}%
}
\recalctypearea
\DeclareNewNoteColumn[%
position=\oddsidemargin+1in
+.7\textwidth
+\marginparsep,
width=\paragraphscolwidth,
font=\footnotesize
]{paragraphs}


\lstset{language=tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{addmargin}[0pt]{.3\textwidth}

  This is the text with a sidenote\makenote*[paragraphs]{\lstinline!\IXS!}


\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

With a current KOMA-script I get this error:

```
ERROR: Improper alphabetic constant.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \IXS 
l.37 \end{document}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

A one-character control sequence belongs after a ` mark.
So I'm essentially inserting \0 here.
```

See the comments below. It seems that it's not so easy to have verbatim commands inside arguments.

Comment: `\lstinline` is a verbatim command. Verbatim commands in the argument of other commands are always dangerous.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I found the `\lstinline` command in the manual of the listings package. Or is my MWE wrong, because no verbatim in the preamble?

Comment: @Schweinebacke No, my question just is, whether my example above is wrong, because `\lstinline` might not be defined by the listings package, but according to you by the verbatim package!

Comment: @Schweinebacke Same error, does it work on your side? You are telling me that you can not nest verbatim commands, right? Then the idea of writing listings into the margin, and this is the question, can't be realised easily, independently from KOMA-script.

Comment: @KeksDose Thanks for the answer. Regarding your annotation that I had to define the note column that way I want to add that I use `geometry` and `twoside=semi`. Hence I extend the space this way just using `\RedeclareNoteColumn[position=\oddsidemargin+1in+\textwidth+\marginparsep,width=\marginparwidth,font=\footnotesize]{marginpar}` (partially taken from `scrlayer-notecolumn.sty`).